# Powershell - Insert column in between specific columns in csv file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have 2 csv files

First file:

```
firstName,secondName
1234,Value1
2345,Value1
3456,Value1
4567,Value3
7645,Value3
```

Second file:

```
firstName,fileSplitter,Csv2ColumnOne,Csv2ColumnTwo,Csv2ColumnThree
1234,,1234,abc,Value1
1234,,1234,asd,Value1
3456,,3456,qwe,Value1
4567,,4567,mnb,Value1
```

I want to insert column `secondName` in the second file in between columns `firstName` and `fileSplitter`.

The result should look like this:

```
firstName,secondName,fileSplitter,Csv2ColumnOne,Csv2ColumnTwo,Csv2ColumnThree
1234,Value1,,1234,abc,Value1
1234,Value1,,1234,asd,Value1
3456,Value1,,3456,qwe,Value1
4567,Value3,,4567,mnb,Value1
```

I'm trying the following code:

```
Function InsertColumnInBetweenColumns
{
Param ($FirstFileFirstColumnTitle, $firstFile, [string]$1stColumnName, [string]$2ndColumnName, [string]$columnMergedFileBeforeInput)

Write-Host "Creating hash table with columns values `"$1stColumnName`" `"$2ndColumnName`" From $OimFileWithMatches"
$hashFirstFileTwoColumns = @{}
Import-Csv $firstFile | ForEach-Object {$hashFirstFileTwoColumns[$_.$1stColumnName] = $_.$2ndColumnName}
Write-Host "Complete."

Write-Host "Appending Merge file with column `"$2ndColumnName`" from file $secondCsvFileWithLocalPath"
Import-Csv $outputCsvFileWithLocalPath | Select-Object $columnMergedFileBeforeInput, @{n=$2ndColumnName; e={
if ($hashFirstFileTwoColumns.ContainsKey($_.$FirstFileFirstColumnTitle)) {
    $hashFirstFileTwoColumns[$_.$FirstFileFirstColumnTitle]
} Else {
    'Not Found'
}}}, * | Export-Csv "$outputCsvFileWithLocalPath-temp" -NoType -Force
Move-Item "$outputCsvFileWithLocalPath-temp" $outputCsvFileWithLocalPath -Force
Write-Host "Complete."
Write-Host ""
}
```

This function will be called in a for loop for each column found in the first file (can contain an indefinite number). For testing, I am only using 2 columns from the first file.

I'm getting an error output resulting the following:

```
Select : Property cannot be processed because property "firstName" already exists.
At C:\Scripts\Tests\Compare2CsvFilesOutput1WithMatchesOnly.ps1:490 char:43
+     Import-Csv $outputCsvFileWithLocalPath | Select $columnMergedFileBeforeInput, @ ...
+                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{firstName=L...ntName=asdfas}:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgume
   ntException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AlreadyExistingUserSpecifiedPropertyNoExpand,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectC
   ommand
```

I know the issue is where it says `Select-Object $columnMergedFileBeforeInput,`.

How can I get the loop statement to insert the column in between the before column (name is specified), and append the rest using `*`?

## Update

Just an fyi, changing this line `Select-Object $columnMergedFileBeforeInput, @{n=$2ndColumnName.....` to this line `Select-Object @{n=$2ndColumnName.....` works, it just attaches the columns out of order. That is why I'm trying to insert the column in between. Maybe if i do it this way but insert the columns in backwards using the for loop, this would work...

Comment: Your expected output makes no sense. File 1 has 5 records, the last refers to `Value3` being associated with `7645`. File 2 has 4 records, and does not reference either of those values, but somehow your expected output includes `Value3` with the fourth record. Please update the question with more reasonable examples.

Comment: Are you simply going line-by-line? As in Record 2 from File1 will be merged with Record 2 in File2 regardless of the content? Will both files have the same number of records? This may be a job for a `For($i=0;$i -lt $file1.count;$i++){}` kind of loop.

Comment: updated first file in question. amount of records in both files can either be same or different.

Comment: Your error states that you are trying to have two properties with the name 'firstname'. It would appear that you are effectively doing the following once your variables are expanded: `Select firstname,firstname,*` So if there is a conflict in property names, what should win?

Comment: Yes, the column `firstName` beforehand was added in test2.csv file to match the values with the column `Csv2ColumnOne`. Now that the value matches found has been added as the first column `firstName` in the test2.csv file, we need to insert the 2nd column from test1.csv file to match the row from the first column `firstName` in test2.csv.

Comment: How do you know where the column is to be inserted? Is it actually based on the other column name so after FirstColumn or is it positional? Silly question I guess. Your logic is base on column name. Why bother with second column? Can you not assume that it just follows the first?

Comment: Does my answer help you @FiddleFreak or dit it not help fixing your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, but it should do the trick. It just adds the property to the record from file2, then reorders the output so `secondName` is the second column. You can output results to csv where required too (ConvertTo-Csv).

```
$file1 = Import-Csv -Path file1.csv
$file2 = Import-Csv -Path file2.csv

$results = @()
ForEach ($record In $file2) {
   Add-Member -InputObject $record -MemberType NoteProperty -Name secondName -Value $($file1 | ? { $_.firstName -eq $record.firstName } | Select -ExpandProperty secondName)
   $results += $record
}

$results | Select-Object -Property firstName,secondName,fileSplitter,Csv2ColumnOne,Csv2ColumnTwo,Csv2ColumnThree
```

Comment: issue with this is if the values from the first columns are out of order, this will print a missmatch in values. Also the values can't be hardcoded due to both files having changeable column names and amount of columns.

Comment: This condition should take care of rows being out of order: `-Value $($file1 | ? { $_.firstName -eq $record.firstName } | Select -ExpandProperty secondName)`. The data having no column can be taken care of as well. One method would be the `-Header` property of `Import-Csv`

Comment: But if columns are out of order, and you don't which column is which because they have no header either - that is a problem.

Comment: indeed, that is why using get-content is very messy, and I prefer the import-csv method. I updated my question with a finding. Might want to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I've created the following function. What it does is find the match (in this case "firstname") and adds the matching columnname to the new array afther the columnname on which the match is made (little difficult to explain in my poor English).

```
function Add-ColumnAfterMatchingColumn{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [string]$MainFile,
    [string]$MatchingFile,
    [string]$MatchColumnName,
    [string]$MatchingColumnName
)

# Import data from two files
$file1 = Import-Csv -Path $MainFile
$file2 = Import-Csv -Path $MatchingFile

# Find column names and order them
$columnnames = $file2 | gm | where {$_.MemberType -like "NoteProperty"} | Select Name | %{$_.Name}
[array]::Reverse($columnnames)

# Find $MatchColumnName index and put the $MatchingColumnName after it
$MatchColumnNameIndex = [array]::IndexOf($columnnames, $MatchColumnName)
if($MatchColumnNameIndex -eq -1){
    $MatchColumnNameIndex = 0
}
$columnnames = $columnnames[0..$MatchColumnNameIndex] + $MatchingColumnName + $columnnames[($MatchColumnNameIndex+1)..($columnnames.Length -1)]

$returnObject = @()
foreach ($item in $file2){
    # Find corresponding value MatchingColumnName in $file1 and add it to the current item
    $item | Add-Member -Name "$MatchingColumnName" -Value ($file1 | ?{$_."$($MatchColumnName)" -eq $item."$($MatchColumnName)"})."$MatchingColumnName" -MemberType NoteProperty

    # Add current item to the returnObject array, in the correct order
    $newItem = New-Object psobject
    foreach ($columnname in [string[]]$columnnames){
        $newItem  | Add-Member -Name $columnname -Value $item."$columnname" -MemberType NoteProperty 
    }
    $returnObject += $newItem
}
return $returnObject
}
```

When you run this function you will have the following output:

```
Add-ColumnAfterMatchingColumn -MainFile C:\Temp\file1.csv -MatchingFile C:\Temp\file2.csv -MatchColumnName "firstname" -MatchingColumnName "secondname" | ft

firstName secondname fileSplitter Csv2ColumnTwo Csv2ColumnThree Csv2ColumnOne
--------- ---------- ------------ ------------- --------------- -------------
1234      Value1                  abc           Value1          1234         
1234      Value1                  asd           Value1          1234         
3456      Value1                  qwe           Value1          3456         
4567      Value3                  mnb           Value1          4567
```